# Making and reporting a logistic regression, stratified by sex and age

Tags: r, statistics, logistic-regression

I have this database with over 6,000 entries and 75 variables. I want to make a few models. The outcome variable is always mortality. The first idea for a model is "Only take male/female, then stratify by age categories, youngest being the reference for the odd ratios (ORs) of the following age categories." (like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BYO7e.jpg)).

To do this, I first made a new dataframe with only all the female entries, and then in the `glm`-function, I subsetted by the youngest age-category (i.e. 18-39). Code looks something like this:

```
df_model_1_all_female <- df %>% filter(Sex == "Female")

model_1_stratgender_age_categories <- glm(mortality ~  Var1 + Var2 + Var3, family="binomial", data= df_model_1_all_female, subset = Age_categories == "18-39")
```

If i subset like that I'd have to make around 7 models (one for every age-category), for only the female category which already seems odd?

Furthermore, if I use this code to become the ORs and confidence intervals:

```
exp(cbind(OR = coef(model_1_stratgender_age_categories_default), confint(model_1_stratgender_age_categories_default)))
```

I'm not sure how to report this. Especially since the youngest age category equals the reference for the further ones.

I suspect I shouldn't use the `subset`-function in the `glm` like that, but I don't know how I should resolve it.

Comment: This is more of a question about modeling, as such it's more suitable for stats.stackexchange.com. Since mortality is involved, the topic of "survival analysis" is relevant; a web search for that term will find some resources.